# How to draw a YUV image to HTML5 canvas without converting it to RGB first?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, yuv

Is it possible to draw a YUV image to HTML5 canvas without converting it to RGB first?

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Teaonly/1f6dfe99e790446bb752), which takes a YUV image, converts it to RGB, and then draws it to the canvas. Is there anyway to skip the RGB converting phase?

I need this for live video streaming, so drawing each frame should be as fast as possible.

Comment: No, Canvas does not natively support YUV.  Some extensions support YUV on canvas but they use a converter much like your gist.  Using live-convertion you might get 10-20+ fps on a good desktop--much less on mobile.  The traditional solution is to buffer the incoming frames so you can present them to the user without stuttering.

Comment: @markE Yeah, but the live stream also includes audio. Would it cause major video-audio synchronization issues?

Comment: "major audio sync issues?"...kinda, yes!  Now that you've added audio to your question, I'd suggest you use an html video element.  If you want to add something with the canvas (annotations, etc), you can always layer a canvas element on top of the video element.